# Split a column into multiple column values based on pattern e.g (a) (b)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I have a problem splitting this column based on (*)

| Column x |
| --- |
| I (a)Some Text (b)Some more Text (c) Text |
| I (a)Some Text (b)Some more Text (c) Text |

I need an output like;

| Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| I (a)Some Text | (b)Some more Text | (c) Text |

Yes there is also a random I before (a) but hoping we can disregard somehow...

Comment: Are there always 3 values to split out?

Comment: And do you need them in order?  Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: Really if these are separate values you should store them separately... pay that cost at write time instead of writing all kinds of convoluted splitting and string parsing queries to break them apart again.

Comment: @Stu Yes there are always 3 values

Comment: @squillman it would make sense to me for them to keep the a b c order, version is SMSS 18

Comment: @AaronBertrand, unfortunately, I'm not in control of how the data is coming in :(

Comment: SSMS is a client for SQL Server. 18 is the client version.  What version of the server are you running?

Comment: Sure, but someone is, and they should know this is bad design.

Comment: @squillman 2019 Dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is something unique to identify each row, you can `PIVOT` based on a `CROSS APPLY` with `STRING_SPLIT()`:

```
DECLARE @x table
(
  [Id] int IDENTITY(1,1),
  [Values] nvarchar(4000) -- this is a terrible column name
);

INSERT @x([Values]) VALUES
  (N'I (a)Some Text (b)Some more Text (c) Text'),
  (N'nonsense (a) mort (b) splungy (c) blat');

;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT Id, [value] = N'(' + f.[value], 
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY x.Id ORDER BY f.[value])
  FROM @x AS x
  CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(x.[Values], N'(') AS f
  WHERE f.[value] LIKE N'_)%'
)
SELECT [1], [2], [3] FROM x
PIVOT (MAX(value) FOR rn IN ([1],[2],[3])) AS p;
```

Results:

```
1               2                   3
------------    -----------------   --------
(a)Some Text    (b)Some more Text   (c) Text
(a) mort        (b) splungy         (c) blat
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9589b1d7db69cf462d67c143a4c89f7d)

And here's [a slightly different one](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a75e1e9a3bafeec78077bff96c9f9801) that returns the `Id` and the exact column headers in the question.